# Is there any way to determine if a nodejs childprocess wants input or is just sending feedback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I had a little freetime so I decided to rewrite all my bash scripts in JavaScript (NodeJS - ES6) with child processes. Everything went smoothly until I wanted to automate user input.

Yes, you can do automate the user input. But there is one Problem - you can't determine if the given `data` event is a feedback or a request for input. At least I can't find a way to do it.

So basically you can do this:

```
// new Spawn.
let spawn = require('child_process');
// new ufw process.
let ufw = spawn('ufw', ['enable']);

// Use defined input.
ufw.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
ufw.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
ufw.stdin.write('y\n');

// Event Standard Out.
ufw.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});

// Event Standard Error.
ufw.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
  // Logerror.
  console.log(err);
});

// When job is finished (with or without error) it ends up here.
ufw.on('close', (code) => {
  // Check if there were errors.
  if (code !== 0) console.log('Exited with code: ' + code.toString());
  // End input stream.
  ufw.stdin.end();
});
```

The above example works totally fine. But there are 2 things giving me an headache:

1. Will `ufw.stdin.write('y\n');` wait until it is needed and what happens if I have multiple inputs? For example 'yes', 'yes', 'no'. Do I have to write 3 lines of `stdin.write()`?
2. Isn't the position where I use `ufw.stdin.write('y\n');` a little confusing? I thought I need the input after my prompt made a request for input so I decided to change my code that my `stdin.write()` could run at the right time, makes sense right? However the only way to check when the 'right' time is on the `stdout.on('data', callback)` event. That makes thinks a little difficult, since I need to know if the prompt is aksing for user input or not...

Here is my code which I think is totally wrong:

```
// new Spawn.
let spawn = require('child_process');
// new ufw process.
let ufw = spawn('ufw', ['enable']);

// Event Standard Out.
ufw.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));

  // Use defined input.
  ufw.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
  ufw.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  ufw.stdin.write('y\n');
});

// Event Standard Error.
ufw.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
  // Logerror.
  console.log(err);
});

// When job is finished (with or without error) it ends up here.
ufw.on('close', (code) => {
  // Check if there were errors.
  if (code !== 0) console.log('Exited with code: ' + code.toString());
  // End input stream.
  ufw.stdin.end();
});
```

My major misunderstanding is when to use `stdin` for user input (automated) and where to place it in my code so it will be used at the right time, for example if I have multiple inputs for something like `mysql_secure_installation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was wondering if it is possible and it seems not. I posted an issue for node which ended up beeing closed: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16214

> ```
> I am asking for a way to determine if the current process is waiting for an input.
> ```
>
> There isn't one. I think you have wrong expectations about pipe I/O
>   because that's simply not how it works.
>
> Talking about expectations, check out expect. There is probably a
>   node.js port if you look around.
>
> I'll close this out because it's not implementable as a feature, and
>   as a question nodejs/help is the more appropriate place.

So if anyone has the same problem as I had you can simply write multiple lines into `stdin` and use that as predefined values. Keep in mind that will eventually break the stream if any input is broken or wrong in feature updates:

```
// new Spawn.
let spawn = require('child_process');
// new msqlsec process.
let msqlsec = spawn('mysql_secure_installation', ['']);
// Arguments as Array.
let inputArgs = ['password', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'];

// Set correct encodings for logging.
msqlsec.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
msqlsec.stdout.setEncoding('utf-8');
msqlsec.stderr.setEncoding('utf-8');

// Use defined input and write line for each of them.
for (let a = 0; a < inputArgs.length; a++) {
  msqlsec.stdin.write(inputArgs[a] + '\n');
}

// Event Standard Out.
msqlsec.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
});

// Event Standard Error.
msqlsec.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
  // Logerror.
  console.log(err);
});

// When job is finished (with or without error) it ends up here.
msqlsec.on('close', (code) => {
  // Check if there were errors.
  if (code !== 0) console.log('Exited with code: ' + code.toString());
  // close input to writeable stream.
  msqlsec.stdin.end();
});
```

---

For the sake of completeness if someone wants to fill the user input manually you can simply start the given process like this:

```
// new msqlsec process.
let msqlsec = spawn('mysql_secure_installation', [''], { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true });
```